# Algorithm to convert a table data to hierarchical tree data using Javascript ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6, hierarchical-data

I have a JSON table data and want to convert to JSON tree data as shown below. I'm looking for an efficient algorithm in JavaScript using any new **ECMAScript 6** operator or statements with a functional approach (not by standard recursive algorithm with ES5)?

Table data:

```
[
   {
      "Children":"4th Grand Father"
   },
   {
      "Name":"4th Grand Father",
      "Children":"3rd Grand Father"
   },
   {
      "Name":"3rd Grand Father",
      "Children":"2nd Grand Father"
   },
   {
      "Name":"2nd Grand Father",
      "Children":"Grand Father"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Grand Father",
      "Children":"Father"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Grand Father",
      "Children":"Uncle"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Uncle",
      "Children":"Cousin"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Father",
      "Children":"Brother"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Father",
      "Children":"Me"
   }
]
```

Tree data:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "4th Grand Father",
    "Children": [
      {
        "Name": "3rd Grand Father",
        "Children": [
          {
            "Name": "2nd Grand Father",
            "Children": [
              {
                "Name": "Grand Father",
                "Children": [
                  {
                    "Name": "Father",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "Name": "Brother"
                      },
                      {
                        "Name": "Me"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "Name": "Uncle",
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "Name": "Cousin"
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? and why do you care about "new EcmaScript 6" (Which is neither new nor correct term) statements?

Comment: Please post the "standard recursive algorithm" that you already have

Comment: You can use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and two simple loops.

Comment: is the data always sorted?

Comment: If you don't know the height of the final tree, then you're going to end up using recursion of one form or another. There are plenty of ES6 features which can make your algorithm easier to read in terms of intent, and thus, easier to modify and maintain. But that doesn't take recursion out of the picture.

Comment: @Norguard understood one of my intent which is to look the code neater. Second is, I was trying to understand a way to solve it using functional composition. The height of the tree is not known, so for code reuse, recursion or iteration has to be applied as I understand.

Comment: @wonderfulworld Iteration is not going to go the way you think.
How many inner loops do you need, if you don't know whether the ancestry ends at "Grandparent" or "Great, Great, Great, Great, Great, Great Grandparent"?

To prevent yourself from insanity, you're going to need to traverse children recursively, rather than build 25 nested loops and hope that's enough, and figure out if you're out of children so that you can break early...

You should consider adding the recursive solution that you already have, and would like cleaned, so that we can figure out where you're starting from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this ES6 function, which uses a `Map`, arrow functions, destructured argument assignment. You could even replace the `concat` call by spread syntax, but I don't think that brings any benefit:

```js
const makeTree = (data) => {
    const hash = data.reduce ( (acc, {Name, Children}) => 
        acc.set(Name, (acc.get(Name) || []).concat(Children)) 
    , new Map );

    const recurse = (Name) => hash.has(Name)
            ?   { Name, Children: hash.get(Name).map(recurse) }
            :   { Name };
    return recurse(undefined).Children;
}

// Sample data
const data = [
   {
      "Children":"4th Grand Father"
   },
   {
      "Name":"4th Grand Father",
      "Children":"3rd Grand Father"
   },
   {
      "Name":"3rd Grand Father",
      "Children":"2nd Grand Father"
   },
   {
      "Name":"2nd Grand Father",
      "Children":"Grand Father"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Grand Father",
      "Children":"Father"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Grand Father",
      "Children":"Uncle"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Uncle",
      "Children":"Cousin"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Father",
      "Children":"Brother"
   },
   {
      "Name":"Father",
      "Children":"Me"
   }
];

const result = makeTree(data);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

#### Explanation:

The *hash* variable is built from an empty `Map`, adding the records to it keyed by *Name*. The value linked to each key is the children information, as an array. When the same *Name* is encountered (i.e. `acc.get(Name)` returns something), the child is added to the already existing array, otherwise (`|| []`) an empty array is created and the child is added to that.

Once the *hash* is complete, the top of the hierarchy is taken by its missing *Name* (`undefined`), and through recursion the children are looked up in the *hash* and added to the final object.

As the result object is an object with a *Children* array, and the desired outcome was in fact that array, it is the *Children* property that gets returned.